# How to have a music on/off setting objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am making a simple game in cocos2d and I wanted to make a simple button toggle to keep sounds on or off. This is what I did so far...

In my `.h`:

```
CCMenuItemImage *sound;
CCMenu *menu2;
```

In my `init`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"musicon"];

// Sound Buttons
        sound = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"music.png" selectedImage:@"music.png" target:self selector:@selector(turnOffSound)];
        sound.scale = 1.1;
        menu2 = [CCMenu menuWithItems:sound, nil];
        menu2.position = ccp(screenCenter.x - 33,screenCenter.y / 5);
        [self addChild:menu2];
```

And then my `turnOffSound` and `turnOnSound` method:

```
-(void) turnOnSound {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"musicon"];
    [self removeChild:sound cleanup:YES];
    [self removeChild:menu2 cleanup:YES];
    sound = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"music.png" selectedImage:@"music.png" target:self selector:@selector(turnOffSound)];
    sound.scale = 1.1;
    menu2 = [CCMenu menuWithItems:sound, nil];
    menu2.position = ccp(screenCenter.x - 33,screenCenter.y / 5);
    [self addChild:menu2];
}
-(void) turnOffSound {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey:@"musicon"];
    [self removeChild:sound cleanup:YES];
    [self removeChild:menu2 cleanup:YES];
    sound = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"music-not.png" selectedImage:@"music-not.png" target:self selector:@selector(turnOnSound)];
    sound.scale = 1.1;
    menu2 = [CCMenu menuWithItems:sound, nil];
    menu2.position = ccp(screenCenter.x - 33,screenCenter.y / 5);
    [self addChild:menu2];
}
```

Right now, the toggle works but only on this screen (this is the title screen), because when I go to another screen, then go back to the title screen, the BOOL is being set to true again. Do you know how I can make it not reset again? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Try to synchronize to NSUserDefault.

Answer (score 1):

Try This, I used this Code and worked always.

```
@interface AppController : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    bool isMusicOn;
    …
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) bool isMusicOn;
@end

@implementation AppController
@synthesize isMusicOn;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"isMusicOn"] != nil)
    {
        self.isMusicOn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isMusicOn"];
    }
    else
    {
        self.isMusicOn = true;
    }

    if(self.isMusicOn)
    {
        [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine].backgroundMusicVolume = 1.0f;
    }
    else 
    {
        [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine].backgroundMusicVolume = 0.0f;
    }
}


-(void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:self.isMusicOn forKey:@"isMusicOn"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
@end


//Create Music button in your Cocos2d Scene

@interface MySettingsScreen : CCLayer 
{
        CCMenuItemSprite *mMusicBtn;
        . .  .
}

//in implementation file
-(void)createButton
{
    AppController *app = (AppController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    NSString *imgName = ((!app.isMusicOn) ? @"mute.png" : @"musicOn.png" );

    CCSprite *music_1   = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:imgName];//spriteWithFile if png is from file
    CCSprite *music_2   = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:imgName];
    music_2.color = ccc3(200,200,200);

    mMusicBtn = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:music_1
                                             selectedSprite:music_2
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(musicBtnPress:) ];

    mMusicBtn.position = ccp(mS.width*0.25f, mS.height*0.1549f);


}


-(void)musicBtnPress:(id)sender
{    
    AppController *app = (AppController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    if(app.isMusicOn)
    {
        [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine].backgroundMusicVolume = 0.0f;

        app.isMusicOn = false;

        mMusicBtn.normalImage = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"mute.png"]; //spriteWithFile if png is from file
        mMusicBtn.selectedImage = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"mute.png"]; //spriteWithFile if png is from file

    }
    else
    {
        app.isMusicOn = true;

        [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine].backgroundMusicVolume = 1.0f;

        mMusicBtn.normalImage = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"musicOn.png"];
        mMusicBtn.selectedImage = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"musicOn.png"]; 

        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"gr-theme.m4a" loop:YES];
    }

}
```